# reg exp match everything inside curly braces

Tags: php, regex

I have this php code and I want to match everything inside curly braces {}

```
$sentence= "This {is|or|and} a {cat|dog|horse} for a {kid|men|women}";
preg_match("/\{.*?\}/", $sentence, $result);
print_r($result);
```

But I get only this output:

```
Array ( [0] => {is|or|and} )
```

But what I need is a result like this:

```
Array ( [0] => is|or|and
[1] => cat|dog|horse
[2] => kid|men|women
 )
```

What regular expression should I use?

Comment: Maybe look at preg_match_all?

Comment: Use `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead?

```
preg_match_all("/\{.*?\}/", $sentence, $result);
```

If you don't want the braces, you can do two things:

Capture the parts inside the braces and use `$result[1]` to get them back like HamZa correctly suggested:

```
preg_match_all("/\{(.*?)\}/", $sentence, $result);
print_r($result[1]);
```

Or use lookarounds (they might be a bit difficult to understand however):

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\{).*?(?=\})/", $sentence, $result);
print_r($result[0]);
```

Note that you can also use `[^}]*` instead of `.*?`, which is usually considered safer.

Comment: @Charlesrogers Use matching groups `\{([^}]*)\}`. You'll find it in `print_r($result[1]);`

Answer (score 3):

To get all results, use [`preg_match_all`](http://regex101.com).

To [improve performance](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy), use `[^}]*` instead of `.*?`.

To get rid of the braces, you can

1. *either* group the contents like `\{([^}]*)\}` and get the result from `$matches[1]`
2. *or* exclude the braces with lookarounds, like `(?<=\{)[^}]*(?=\})`
3. *or* exclude the first brace with `\K` and the second with a lookahead like `\{\K[^}]*(?=\})`

Comment: ~hehe like always, nice answer. Especially for that not-so-known escape character `\K` :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `preg_match_all`, yes, but you also need to modify your Regex to be `\{(.*?)\}`. [See this Regex101 for proof](http://regex101.com/r/sS4gD7). In your original Regex you weren't grouping the results and thus getting the braces as well.

Comment: Don't use rubular as a "proof" for a PHP question ;). [Regex101](http://regex101.com) uses PCRE, so that would be more suitable.

Comment: @m.buettner, fair enough. Did you build that site?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm just a bit pedantic when it comes to regex flavors ;). We encourage people to always mention their regex flavor when asking regex questions, so we shouldn't provide them with answers that don't respect that flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match_all`

```
$sentence= "This {is|or|and} a {cat|dog|horse} for a {kid|men|women}";
preg_match_all("/\{[^}]+}/", $sentence, $result);
print_r($result[0]);
```

will give you

```
Array
    (
        [0] => {is|or|and}
        [1] => {cat|dog|horse}
        [2] => {kid|men|women}
    )
```

Comment: I think you meant `[^}]+` :-)

Comment: @HamZa no I meant what I have there in the regex part

Comment: I have made the change :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `preg_match` to `preg_match_all` and `$result` to `$result[1]` and modify the regex slightly as below:

```
<?php
$sentence= "This {is|or|and} a {cat|dog|horse} for a {kid|men|women}";
preg_match_all("/\{(.*?)\}/", $sentence, $result);
print_r($result[1]);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => is|or|and
    [1] => cat|dog|horse
    [2] => kid|men|women
)
```